# theano list of matrices as function argument

Tags: python, list, function, matrix, theano

Is it possible to define a function in theano that takes a list of matrices (scalars, vectors) as an input argument?

Here a simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import theano as T
import theano.tensor as TT

a = []
a.append(np.zeros((2, 3)))
a.append(np.ones((4, 3)))

T_a = TT.matrices(len(a))
T_z = TT.concatenate(T_a)
fun = T.function(T_a,T_z)

print fun(a[0],a[1])

#but how to make this work?
print fun(a)
```

What happens if list 'a' has not two but thousands of elements with different shapes?
the only thing that comes in my mind is to concatenate these elements to one large matrix and then proceed with it. 
Is not there a nicer solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
def my_func(*args): 
    for list in args:
        # stuff here

# ln being your lists.
my_func(l1, l2, l3...)
```

What happens there is that when you use *args in a function definition it means you can pass any number of positional arguments.